# auto update form with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

I want the text i type in

```
<input type="text" name="text1">
```

will automatically be updated in

```
<input type="text" name="text2">
```

by using JavaScript.

Anyone know how to solve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please share with us the attempts you have made so far? As it currently stands, it just looks like you're asking us to do your work for you - this is not how [so] operates.

Comment: Please take a look at the [ask] section of the [help] for more information on how to ask a good question for [so].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `onkeyup` event and populate the second `<input>` with the text of the first one, like this:

```js
var inp1 = document.getElementsByName('text1')[0],
    inp2 = document.getElementsByName('text2')[0];

inp1.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  inp2.value = this.value;
});
```

```html
<p>Input 1: <input type="text" name="text1" placeholder="write something here..."></p>
<p>Input 2: <input type="text" name="text2" placeholder="ant it will show up here..."></p>
```

Test it using the "Run code snippet" button.